# What is the meaning of $(x^2+y^2)^n$? Is this an already known geometric object?

Tags: geometry, recreational-mathematics, contest-math, circles, research

We all know that $x^2+y^2=r^2$ is a circle. What does $(x^2+y^2)^2$ signify? In general, what is $(x^2+y^2)^n$?

Comment: It remains a circle... assuming that $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$. The reason behind it is simply given by the fact that you can always take the n-th root on both sides and you don't change the possibile values...

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but it's interesting to note that if $x^2 + y^2 - r^2 = 0$ is squared on both sides, then the resulting polynomial still determines a circle, but all the points are multiplicity two roots of the equation now.

Comment: Perhaps you're thinking of the "[superellipses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superellipse)", a.k.a. "(even-degree) Fermat curves" $x^{2n} + y^{2n} = 1$, which become "successively more square" as $n \to \infty$...?

Comment: @ hAcKnRoCk : Sorry I cannot understand your question because on one hand you write x²+y²=r² which is an equation and on the other hand (x²+y²)² which is not an equation (there is no = in it). What exactly do you want to compare ?

Comment: @ JJacquelin, yes. there is no = in it. i do not want to compare but understand generalization to higher dimensions.

Comment: Higher dimensions = more **variables**.

Comment: Look [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28x%5E2%2By%5E2%29%5E2%3D1).

Answer (score 3):

Using the transformation: $$x=r\cos(t),~~y=r\sin(t)$$ there is no change. I mean the circle remains unchanged.

Comment: Thanks. But i am asking only about the LHS. I have edited the question to make it more clear